# Which Godzilla movie had him survive getting hit by a meteorite?

Tags: story-identification, godzilla

Details: I think it was made after 2000, i forgot the meteors size but it looked like it might've been the same size as Godzilla, after he was hit he stood in the middle of the crater unscathed, unflinching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like [Godzilla: Final Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_Final_Wars), which was released in 2004.

The "meteor" you refer to is actually a planet named [Gorath](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Gorath). Within the planet, however, is [Monster X](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_X). By destroying Gorath, Godzilla unleashes Monster X.